# Delete large batch of files with same file name in different directories - cpanel/LAMP

Tags: lamp, cpanel, putty

I have a bunch of old deprecated pages on a site i am working in.

Let's say the site has different product pages:
site.com/product1
site.com/product2
site.com/product3
......
site.com/product450

Inside each of these directories is a page called productreveiw.php

Due to a bad initial design, this page existed in every directory.  Long ago, this was pointed to a single product review page (site.com/productreview.php).

Everything works great, but there are 450 of these old files out there, one in each directory.

I want to delete them out without going into each directory in ftp and manually deleting them.

Is there a way to do this in cpanel->file manager?  I was able to search and find them all, but I could take no action after that, except opening the directory they are in.  I was hoping to be able to select all and delete them in 1 shot.

I'm sure there is a way to do this in SSH, but I'm not real comfortable in there and was hoping for a more user friendly route through cpanel or ftp.

Thanks in advance as always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were no takers on this question.

I ended up deleting everything through SSH, which wasn't that hard after I got used to it.

I searched for files like this:

> find . -name "index1.php" -delete

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for SSH method and came here but deleting by ftp is easy. Just search them and delete them using ftp client.

Comment: This one depends on the possibilities of the FTP client, not all can do that.