# Command in terminal to delete multiple files - CPanel, shared hosting infected with virus

Tags: php, .htaccess, terminal, cpanel

Today, Hosted gator reported that I have 30K files infected on my shared hosting. Around 25K was the same file, multiple times. I deleted them in one shot through the terminal with:

```
find . -name "0x1337.php" -delete
```

Reference:
[Delete large batch of files with same file name in different directories - cpanel/LAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14820195/delete-large-batch-of-files-with-same-file-name-in-different-directories-cpane)

One such example path was:

`/home1/..../public_html/.........com/wp-includes/js/tinymce/skins/lightgray/fonts/0x1337.php: SL-PHP-BACKDOOR-GENERIC-md5-cavg.UNOFFICIAL FOUND`

Around 6K are still left:

`/home1/.../public_html/......com/blog/wp-content/plugins/related-posts-slider/styles/.htaccess: SL-HTACCESS-GENERIC-xo.UNOFFICIAL FOUND`

If I used this to delete:

`find . -name ".htaccess" -delete` → All `.htaccess` will be deleted.
Is there was to refactor so only infected files can be deleted?

Can this be taken as a clue → `-xo.UNOFFICIAL FOUND`?

Comment: If you have a text file with all the infected filenames, you can `cat filelist.txt | xargs rm`. Just be really careful that the file only contains file names you actually want to delete.

Comment: No, it has a mixed name, Hostgator created a file by the name of malware.txt, but it has other virus names such as: `0x1337.php` Though they are already deleted by: `find . -name "index1.php" -delete`

Comment: Can you turn that file into a list of files to delete? Maybe with a mixture of `grep` and `cut` (e.g. something like `grep BACKDOOR malware.txt | cut -d ':' -f1` to find all files with `SL-PHP-BACKDOOR-GENERIC-md5-cavg.UNOFFICIAL FOUND` in the line)?

Comment: Yes, I can do that. currently, mwlare.txt is kept in-home, malaware.txt has sibling folder public_html, in-home as a parent I have created newmawlare.txt = https://ibb.co/kgLjJXT I am new to terminal what will be the exact command to execute it? Thanks.

Comment: _Aside:_ Has the vulnerability been patched that allowed these files to be uploaded/created in the first place?

Comment: Start out with `cat malaware.txt | xargs -n 1 -p rm` -- `-n 1` will ensure it processes one file at a time, `-p` will prompt you to confirm every removal. This way you can check the first few files to see that it's actually working correctly. Then you can CTRL+C and run it again without `-p`.

Comment: I have deleted all unused plugins from WordPress, probably they were causing the issues.

Comment: I tried, and it says rm: cannot remove `SL-HTACCESS-GENERIC-md5-esb.UNOFFICIAL': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `FOUND\r': No such file or directory  -- I used this → `cat nmalaware.txt | xargs -n 1 rm`

Comment: I need to guess a little, because every file name you mention has different spelling. But for the `cat <filename>` part you need to use the file that contains only the file names. So the result of that `grep` command.

Comment: @rickdenhaan I am not a Linux guy, could you simplify with the command?

Comment: I would restore from backup and patch immediately.

Comment: @Stackchampu there's not really anything I can tell you that would simplify things. I already told you the exact, literal commands you need to execute. You just need to use the correct filename(s).

Comment: Ok sir, Can you guide me since the files name can be different, is there any regex method that can take varied file names?

Comment: Or let it be put in a different way, in a `nmalaware.txt` file every file path is different how to delete them all through terminal comand.

Comment: That is exactly what the `cat | xargs` command does. At this point, perhaps you should consider asking someone to help you directly or just deleting _all_ files and restoring your site from version control or a clean backup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an attempt to clarify the steps I mentioned in the comments, I'll write it all out here.

I'm going to be *super* verbose here to explain what's happening.

My assumption is that Hostgator has provided you with a file named `malware.txt` that contains entries that look like this:

```
/path/to/file.php: SOME-MALWARE FOUND
/path/to/another/file.php: SOME-OTHER-MALWARE FOUND
/path/to/clean/file.php: CLEAN
```

In other words: `malware.txt` contains a mix of files that were flagged as containing malware and files that were considered clean and you want to keep.

The first step is to turn this file into a new file that only contains the file paths. We'll use `grep` and `cut` for this.

```
grep 'SOME-MALWARE' malware.txt | cut -d ':' -f1 > filelist.txt
```

- `grep 'SOME-MALWARE' malware.txt` will find all lines in `malware.txt` that contain the string `SOME-MALWARE` anywhere. This is on purpose so you can break the list down into smaller sets and target individual malwares at a time.
- `|` will send each line to the next command
- `cut -d ':' -f1` will split each line by a delimiter (`:`) and keep only the given field (`1` -- the first field, so everything from the beginning of the line up to the first `:` character)
- `> filelist.txt` will send the results to `filelist.txt`.

Now, with the sample set, `filelist.txt` should contain the following:

```
/path/to/file.php
```

(to target `/path/to/another/file.php` change `grep` to look for `SOME-OTHER-MALWARE`)

The next step is to delete those files. We will use `cat` and `rm` for that. Since we cannot pipe directly to `rm` using `|`, we will use the `xargs` command to do that.

```
cat filelist.txt | xargs -n1 -p rm
```

- `cat filelist.txt` will read all lines in `filelist.txt` one by one
- `|` will send each line to the next command
- `xargs -n1 -p rm` will send each line as an argument to the `rm` command.

  - `-n1` will ensure it processes one line at a time (without this, it will bunch lines together into a single `rm` command to delete multiple files at once)
  - `-p` will prompt you to confirm that you want to continue before actually performing the `rm` command

The reason for `-p` is so you can verify that this all works correctly. Once you've verified that, you can remove the `-p` argument if you want.

Note that this assumes all your filenames are pretty basic. If they contain special characters or spaces, these will need to be escaped or it will break.

For example, if you have a file named `/path/to/some file.php`, this code will try to remove the files `/path/to/some` and `file.php`.

If you notice trouble here, you can adjust the `xargs` command like this:

```
cat filelist.txt | xargs -I "{}" -n1 -p rm {}
```

The `-I "{}"` part will wrap the input argument (the filename from `cat`) in double quotes, the `{}` at the end will make sure `rm` uses the wrapped argument instead of the original.

If you run this command multiple times, you will probably see a lot of "file not found" errors. That is expected for files that were already deleted the last time you ran it so shouldn't be anything to worry about.

I hope this clarifies things, let me know if this is unclear in any way.

Comment: Thanks, Sir, This line → `grep 'SOME-MALWARE' malware.txt | cut -d ':' -f1 > filelist.txt` cant this be used in the more generic way → `grep malware.txt | cut -d ':' -f1 > filelist.txt' Anything after `:` should be deleted from the path and new file be created.

Comment: If you don’t want to filter the file list and just want all the files, then use `cat malware.txt | cut -d ':' -f1 > filelist.txt`